# How to access the iframe #document using cheeriojs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iframe, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scraping the anime videos page [jkanime], but I'm having problems with the formats mp4 videos since they are in an iframe #document.

I have tried to make querie using cheerio, but I only manage to get two src that are from facebook plugins. It's as if I did not recognize the ifram where the mp4 are.

**In chrome dev tool I put the following:**
$('#jkvideo_html5_api source')

And the src of the mp4 shows me. But when I use the same query with cheerio nothing happen.

I've been trying for weeks trying to get the mp4 but I could not. Any help will be more than welcome.

**Image**

[devtool source code section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NipTY.jpg)

```
  const getAnimeVideo = async (id: string, chapter: number) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${url}${id}/${chapter}/`);
    const body = await res.text();
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
    const arr = [];
    $('iframe').each((index, element) => {
      const $element = $(element);
      const x = $element.attr('src');
      console.log(x);
      arr.push(x);
    });
    return arr;
}
```

**Output Obtained**

```
{
  "videos": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fjkanimetv%2F&width=132&layout=box_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=false&share=false&height=21&appId=149291901844100",
    "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://jkanime.net/tokyo-ghoul/1/&width=76&layout=box_count&action=like&size=small&show_faces=false&share=false&height=65&appId=149291901844100"
  ]
}
```

**Output that I want to obtain**

```
{
  "videos": [
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/markesito.appspot.com/blakkkk-88.mp4"
   ]
}
```

**Update: 10:52 pm**

Using puppeteer,I found the way to access the iframe with the class "player_conte". It shows me the following output in the terminal:

[_navigationURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Fko.jpg)

Now .. what I do not know is how to get the link from _navigationURL

To be able to use it with cheerio and make reference to the source of the video.

**Code Updated**

```js
const getAnimeVideo = async (id: string, chapter: number) => {
  const BASE_URL = `${url}${id}/${chapter}/`  // => https://jkanime.net/tokyo-ghoul/1/
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch() 
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(BASE_URL);

  const elementHandle = await page.$('.player_conte')
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
  const $ = cheerio.load(`${frame}`);
  console.log(frame)
}
```

Comment: That's the rendered html, not the source. The source is what you see when you do "view source". You might want to use puppeteer for this.

Comment: @pguardiario Any example , how to solved?

Comment: @pguardiario managed to refer to the iframe, but I do not know how to get the src with puppeteer.

Comment: If you switch to puppeteer you need to make a new question. This question is about cheerio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using puppeteer

```
const getAnimeVideo = async (id: string, chapter: number) => {
  const BASE_URL = `${url}${id}/${chapter}/`  // => https://jkanime.net/tokyo-ghoul/1/
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch() 
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(BASE_URL);
  const elementHandle = await page.$('.player_conte')
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
  const video = await frame.$eval('#jkvideo_html5_api', el =>
  Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('source')).map(e => e.getAttribute("src")));
  return video;
 }
```